# GWT app auto-cache problem

Tags: apache, http, gwt, internet-explorer-7, apache-config

We need to release our GWT app using different URLs for each version, otherwise IE7 (possibly others) seem to cache the old app (leading to grisly bugs). To clarify version/URLs:

- http://www.xyz.com/r001/ (version 1)
- http://www.xyz.com/r002/ (version 2)
- ...

Has anybody else seen this? Anybody know how to solve/circumvent in another way? Mayhap there is some Apache setting? Or perhaps some HTTP header? Thanks!

Comment: What are your HTTP cache headers on the host page and/or the nocache.js file?

Comment: @BobV Doesn't matter if that file is cached but other files, including the html pages, respond with a `304`. Whence the "grisly bugs", since there will be different logic with different versions all over.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Cache-Control` response header to `no-cache`.

For better control over caching, check out Apache Entity Tags: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag